# How to restrict user access to prevent visiting other user profiles

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication

In my app, no anonimus uzer can switch to another profile, he only should know the pers_id.
How can I forbid doing this?
my views.py:

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    pers_id = request.GET.get('pers_id', None)
    if pers_id is None:
        return redirect('/')

    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(profile_id=pers_id)
    try:
        user_memories = Memory.objects.get(profile_id=pers_id)
    except Memory.DoesNotExist:
        user_memories = False
    context = {'memories': user_memories, 'user_profile': user_profile}

    return render(request, 'home.html', context)



def vk_callback(request):
    try:
        vk_user = UserSocialAuth.objects.get(provider='vk-oauth2', user=request.user)
        vk_profile = vk_user.extra_data
        user_info = UserInfoGetter(vk_profile['access_token'])
        pers_id, first_name, last_name, photo_url = user_info.get_vk_info()

        try:
            user_profile = Profile.objects.get(profile_id=pers_id)
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            user_profile = Profile.objects.create(
                profile_id=pers_id,
                first_name=first_name,
                last_name=last_name,
                photo_url=photo_url
            )

        user_profile.first_name = first_name
        user_profile.last_name = last_name
        user_profile.photo_url = photo_url
        user_profile.save()

        return redirect(f'/home?pers_id={pers_id}')

    except UserSocialAuth.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return redirect(home)
```

When the user take auntification he redirected to /home?pers_id={pers_id}. if authorized user knows the pers_id he can check antoher profiles. How can i fix it?

Comment: why do you need a personal id if the user id already logged in? Everything should be in request.user. Profile should just have a Foreign Key to User.

Comment: i need to save the avatars and memories from users. I thinks, that it willl be more convenient

Comment: here is the recommended way of extending django user model e.g. with profile data like picture etc. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model